# SD card used as internal storage not showing any file

Tags: internal-storage, 6.0-marshmallow, sd-card

I am using SD card as internal storage in Marshmallow. After few days one day suddenly it stop showing any file on my phone. When I have checked the storage position in phone it is showing the memory used but no files are showing zero. I have tries connecting the phone to PC but then also no file is showing in the internal storage, also it is not creating any drive and hence no card repair tool is working in PC. When I have used the card with adapter in PC it is not at all detecting the card (which is probable due to card formatted as internal storage in marshmallow)
Now I am not able to save any single file,application on my phone because it gives error 'No enough space left on the memory'.

Anybody please advise what can be done.